# How to save and restore the content of a ListModel?

Tags: qt, qml, settings

I am able to save settings for list items which is statically created using `Component.onComponent` method. But Settings for statically created list items take affect after reopening app. I would like to save settings for dynamically created list model. I am unable to save Settings for a dynamically created list item. The code below does that a list item is on and off while clicking Show/Hide action. When I reopen the app, created list item disappears. How to save list item using Setting?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
ApplicationWindow {
    id:root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property variant addlist
    property int countt2: 0
    Settings{
        id:mysetting4
        property alias ekranCosinus: root.countt2
    }
    function listonoff(){
        if(countt2%2==1){
            return true
          }
        else if(countt2%2==0){
            return false
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: addlist

        onTriggered:   listonoff()

    }
    addlist: favourite2
    /* main.qml */
    menuBar: MenuBar {
            Menu {
                title: "&Edit"
                MenuItem { action: favourite2 }
            }
    }
    Action {
        id:favourite2
         text: qsTr("Show/Hide")
         onTriggered: {
            countt2++
            console.log(countt2)
               if(listonoff()===true){
                   return list_model.insert(list_model.index,{ title: "First item."} )
                }
                else if(listonoff()===false){
                   return list_model.remove(list_model.index)
                }
           }
        }
        ListView {
            id:contactlist
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            focus: true
            interactive: true
            clip: true
            model: ListModel {
                id:list_model
            }
            delegate: ListItem {
                text: model.title
                height:60
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: mouse
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite curious that you expect that saving a single integer value will somehow be able to store the content of an arbitrary data model... It doesn't work even for the static model data, it is only "restored" **because it is static** - it is part of the code, you are not really saving and restoring anything.

If you want to store all that data, you will have to serialize it when your app quits, and deserialize it when the app starts.

You could still use `Settings`, but to store a string value, that will represent the serialized data.

The easiest way to do it is to transfer the model items back and forth with a JS array, this way the JS `JSON` object functionality can be used to easily serialize and deserialize the data:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
  id: main
  width: 640
  height: 480
  visible: true

  property string datastore: ""

  Component.onCompleted: {
    if (datastore) {
      dataModel.clear()
      var datamodel = JSON.parse(datastore)
      for (var i = 0; i < datamodel.length; ++i) dataModel.append(datamodel[i])
    }
  }

  onClosing: {
    var datamodel = []
    for (var i = 0; i < dataModel.count; ++i) datamodel.push(dataModel.get(i))
    datastore = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
  }

  Settings {
    property alias datastore: main.datastore
  }

  ListView {
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: ListModel {
      id: dataModel
      ListElement { name: "test1"; value: 1 }
    }
    delegate: Text {
      text: name + " " + value
    }
  }

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
    onClicked: {
      if (mouse.button === Qt.LeftButton) {
        var num = Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
        dataModel.append({ "name": "test" + num, "value": num })
      } else if (dataModel.count) {
        dataModel.remove(0, 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The application begins with a single data model value, more data items can be added or removed by pressing the left and right mouse button respectively.

As long as the application is closed properly, the data model will be copied into an array, which will be serialized to a string, which will be stored by the `Settings` element. So upon relaunching the app, if the data string is present, the model is cleared to remove the initial value so it is not duplicated, the data string is deserialized back into an array, which is iterated to restore the content of the data model. Easy peasy.

Of course, you could also use the `LocalStorage` API as well, or even write a simple file reader and writer by exposing a C++ object to QML. All this approach needs is to be able to store and retrieve a single string.

Comment: Many thanks for answer.I tried your app, reopened it. Interestingly first it didn't work on Windows, then I tried it on Linux it works:) I am new to programming and I don't know c++ so I cannot extend the app with c++. I am doing a mobile app with QML and JS which has list menu, There are so many pages in it. I have two tabs, one is main tab other is favorite tab. I added star action per page. When star is checked the page should be added to favorite tab as a list item.

Comment: You have to `app.setOrganizationName()`, `app.setOrganizationDomain()` and `app.setApplicationName()` in main.cpp to get the settings to work on windows and probably android too.

Comment: I got errors like: `..\untitled\main.cpp(16): error C2660: 'QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName': function does not take 0 arguments
..\untitled\main.cpp(17): error C2660: 'QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain': function does not take 0 arguments
..\untitled\main.cpp(18): error C2660: 'QCoreApplication::setApplicationName': function does not take 0 arguments`

Comment: Thanks. I work on Linux, so no probem with it :) I will also test it on Android

Comment: Just put some org name, domain name and app name. It is required so that the system can store the data in the appropriate place.

Comment: It works also for Android, reopened, restarted the device, still works without adding org and domain names. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @dtech I have problem using onClosing within Page{} . onClosing only works in ApplicationWindow{}. I tried onCanGoBackChanged method instead of onClosing, it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I gave you the code to make it work, it is up to you to plug it in your design. I have no idea what you are doing and how your application is designed. You will have to find a way to trigger the functionality at the right time. If you have further questions, post a new question with the particular issue. This one was about saving and restoring the model, which has been answered.

Comment: Sorry. I will prepare a new question.

Comment: I reached maximum limit about asking question :)

Comment: @dtech, regarding array size `dataModel.count`  does not work for me, while `datamodel.length` works, is that system dependent?

Comment: @MohammadKanan you are probably mixing up `ListModel` and JS array - `ListModel` has `count` and JS array has `length`, both are system independent.

Comment: Want to emphasize @dtech's comment: you need to 'app.setOrganizationName()', 'app.setOrganizationDomain()' and 'app.setApplicationName()' in main.cpp to get the settings to work