# How to access and control the content of a ListModel from another QML

Tags: qt, qml, settings

I had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730166/how-to-save-and-restore-the-content-of-a-listmodel). But this solution worked only for one-paged QML file. I build a QML app that contains many pages, so I made a favorite tab that contains Add/Remove action. There is a list model in favorite tab page. In my opinion, in order to add any page to the favorite list, it is necessary to call the favorite list model from the sample page, so when a user clicked the action, the page should be added to the favorite page as a list item. I have two examples. First example is one-paged QML and it adds/removes list item. But second example doesn't adds/removes the sample page to favorite list page. How can I access, save and restore the content of the list model using QML or Java Script? Thanks.

***First example:***

[image]

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
ApplicationWindow{
    id:main
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible:true
    title: "Menu"
    property string datastore: ""
    property int countt2: 0
    Settings{
        property alias datastore: main.datastore
        property alias mycount: main.countt2
    }
    menuBar:MenuBar {
        Menu{
        title: main.title
            Action {
                id:action2
                text: qsTr("On/Off")
                onTriggered:{
                    countt2++
                    console.log("triggered works.Count/2: "+ countt2%2)
                    if(countt2%2==1){
                        console.log("it must be added")
                        dataModel.append({ "title": "Application Tools" })
                    }
                    else if(countt2%2==0){
                        console.log("list must be removed. count/2: "+countt2%2)
                        return dataModel.remove(dataModel.index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        if(datastore){
            dataModel.clear()
            var datamodel=JSON.parse(datastore)
            for (var i=0; i<datamodel.length; ++i) dataModel.append(datamodel[i])
        }
        console.log("onCompleted works right now.")
    }
    onClosing: {
        var datamodel = []
        for (var i=0;i<dataModel.count; ++i) datamodel.push(dataModel.get(i))
        datastore=JSON.stringify(datamodel)
        console.log("datastore: "+datastore)
    }
        ListView {
            id:malist
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            focus: true
            interactive: true
            clip: true
            model:FavModel{
            id:dataModel
            }
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                width: parent.width
                text: model.title
            }
        }
}
```

**FavModel.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
ListModel {
    id:dataModel
    }
```

***Second Example:***

[image]

[image]

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
ApplicationWindow{
    id:main
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible:true
    title: "Example App"
    initialPage:TabbedPage {
        title: main.title
        Tab{
            title:"APPS"
        ListView {
            id:malist
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            focus: true
            interactive: true
            clip: true
            model:ListModel {
            id:appModel
            ListElement { title: qsTr("Page1"); source: "qrc:/SampePage.qml" }
            }
            delegate: ListItem {
                text: model.title
                onClicked: pageStack.push(model.source)
            }
        }
        }
        Favourites{}
    }
}
```

**Favourites.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
Tab{
    title:"FAVORITES"
ListView {
    id:favorites
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    focus: true
    interactive: true
    clip: true
    model:FavModel {
    id:favModel
    }
    delegate: ListItem {
        text: model.title
        onClicked: pageStack.push(model.source)
    }
}
}
```

**FavModel.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
    id:dataModel
    }
```

**SamplePage.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
Page{
    title:qsTr("Page1")
    appBar.maxActionCount: 2
    id:sampleapp
    property string datastore: ""
    property int countt2: 0
    Settings{
        id:mysetting4
        property alias datastore: sampleapp.datastore
        property alias mycount: sampleapp.countt2
    }
    FavModel{
        id:dataModel
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("onCompleted works right now.")
        if(datastore){
            dataModel.clear()
            var datamodel = JSON.parse(datastore)
            for (var i=0; i<datamodel.length; ++i) dataModel.append(datamodel[i])
        }
    }
    onCanGoBackChanged: {
        var datamodel=[]
        for (var i=0; i<dataModel.count; ++i) datamodel.push(dataModel.get(i))
        datamodel = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
        console.log("datastore: "+datastore)
    }
    actions: [
        Action {
          id:favourite2
            onTriggered:{
                countt2++
                console.log("Count/2: "+ countt2%2)
                if(countt2%2==1){
                    console.log("List must be added")
                    dataModel.append({ "title": "Application Tools", "source": "qrc:/SampePage.qml" })
                }
                else if(countt2%2==0){
                    console.log("List must be removed.")
                    return dataModel.remove(dataModel.index)
                }
            }
            icon.name: "toggle/star"
            toolTip: qsTr("Add/Remove")
        }
    ]
}
```

*I couldn't make Qt Quick Controls 2.0 only example in second example, I had to use fluid qml library because it is simple to make list menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have 2 problems:

- The first is that you are not saving the list in `datastorage`

---

```
[...]
datamodel = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
[...]
```

Must be:

```
datastore = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
```

- The second is that you are saving the data at the wrong time, the `onCanGoBackChanged` event occurs after the page is loaded. In general the approach must be that the data is loaded when the item is finished loading, and the data is saved before the item is destroyed, so it is appropriate to use the `Component.onCompleted` and `Component.onDestruction` events.

---

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("onCompleted works right now.")
    if(datastore){
        dataModel.clear()
        var datamodel = JSON.parse(datastore)
        for (var i=0; i<datamodel.length; ++i) dataModel.append(datamodel[i])
    }
}
Component.onDestruction: {
    console.log("onDestruction works right now.")
    var datamodel=[]
    for (var i=0; i<dataModel.count; ++i) datamodel.push(dataModel.get(i))
    datastore = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
    console.log("datastore: "+datastore)
}
```

Another minor error, because I think it's a test code. let's say there is no data in `dataModel` and that `countt2` is even, so you're going to want to delete a non-existent data from the `dataModel`.

**Update:**

`Settings` is used to store the data and be able to restore after closing the application, but if you want to share data between several files a possible solution is to implement a `singleton`, as this is a single element that exists in the whole application. It will be easy to modify it anywhere.

To build a singleton we create an .qml file with the following structure:

**Shared.qml**

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property var favModel: FavModel{}
}
```

Then we add another file called qmldir:

**qmldir**

```
singleton Shared 1.0 Shared.qml
```

Then I import it and we use it in the following way:

```
import "."

[...]

Shared.favModel.some_function()
```

for example in your specific case:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
import "."

ApplicationWindow{
    id:main
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible:true
    title: "Example App"

    property string datastore: ""
    Settings{
        property alias datastore: main.datastore
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("onCompleted works right now.")
        if(datastore){
            Shared.favModel.clear()
            var datamodel = JSON.parse(datastore)
            for (var i=0; i<datamodel.length; ++i) Shared.favModel.append(datamodel[i])
        }
    }

    Component.onDestruction: {
        console.log("onDestruction works right now.")
        var datamodel=[]
        for (var i=0; i<Shared.favModel.count; ++i) datamodel.push(Shared.favModel.get(i))
        datastore = JSON.stringify(datamodel)
        console.log("datastore: "+datastore)
    }
    [...]
}
```

**SamplePage.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2
import Fluid.Controls 1.0
import "."

Page{
    title:qsTr("Page1")
    appBar.maxActionCount: 2
    id:sampleapp

    actions: [
        Action {
            id:favourite2
            onTriggered:{
                Shared.favModel.append({ "title": "Application Tools", "source": "qrc:/SamplePage.qml" })
            }
            icon.name: "toggle/star"
            toolTip: qsTr("Add/Remove")
        }
    ]
}
```

**Favourites.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import Fluid.Controls 1.0

import "."

Tab{
    title:"FAVORITES"
    id:favtab

    ListView {
        id:favorites
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        focus: true
        interactive: true
        clip: true
        model: Shared.favModel
        delegate: ListItem {
            text: model.title
            onClicked: pageStack.push(model.source)
        }
    }
}
```

The complete and updated example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48891034)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time. It is helpful to see two major mistakes. Actually I try to add the list item to Favourite.qml, not in SamplePage.qml. For example I have 20 pages, those pages should be optionaly  able to be added to Favourite tabbed page as list items. I couldn't find any way to connect Favourite's List Model to add the list item in it. Could you enlighten this please? [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Zzgyh) is a picture that I try to add.

Comment: @EdipAhmet Do you want to modify FavModel from Favorites.qml from an event that is done in SamplePage.qml?

Comment: [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TYjGfzCqk9/) is SamplePage, [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QhpmJrYHY4/) is Favourites.qml page. I try to add the list item to Favourite tab page by clicking on the star action. I tried this, console.log seems working but it doesn't add the list item to Favourite's list model. Yes I try to add list item dynamically to Favorites.qml from SamplePage.qml.

Comment: Sorry, Favorites.qml is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/393gpZxtVD/) .

Comment: @EdipAhmet I have updated my answer and the code of the repository, try it and tell me if you have problems.

Comment: Many thanks @eyllanesc It is what I was try to do for 1 week:) I learnt very important feature of Qt with your help. Allah blesses you!