# Get qml listModel data saved to JSON in jsonObject c++ source file dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, qml

> get data from qml list model to c++ and
>   save all to QJsonObject dynamically. 
>   need help
>   Thanks in advance..

Qt source file code:

```
void JsonCreator::saveResults(){
    emit resultsDataChanged();
}

QString JsonCreator::addUniqueSuffix(const QString path, const QString fileName) const
{
    if (!QFile::exists(path + fileName)) {
        return fileName;
    }
    QFileInfo fileInfo(fileName);
    QString ret;

    QString secondPart = fileInfo.completeSuffix();
    QString firstPart;
    if (!secondPart.isEmpty()) {
        secondPart = "." + secondPart;
        firstPart = fileName.left(fileName.size() - secondPart.size());
    } else {
        firstPart = fileName;
    }
    for (int ii = 1; ; ii++) {
        ret = QString("%1 (%2)%3").arg(firstPart).arg(ii).arg(secondPart);
        if (!QFile::exists(path + ret)) {
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

void JsonCreator::testData(const QString &currentTest,const QString str){
    convertQtToJson(currentTest, str);
}

 void JsonCreator::convertQtToJson(const QString currentTest, const QString data){
    QJsonDocument  json;
    QJsonArray recordsArray;
    QJsonObject  recordObject;

    QJsonObject dataObject;
    dataObject.insert(data);// how to get the qml multiple listmodel data and save to this 
    recordObject.insert(currentTest, dataObject);

    QJsonDocument doc(recordObject);
    qDebug() << doc.toJson();

    recordsArray.push_back(recordObject);
    json.setArray(recordsArray);
    QString path = "C:/git/qt/ts-ui/";
    QString dateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
    QString file = addUniqueSuffix(path, "testdemo.json");
    QFile jsonFile(path+file);
    jsonFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    jsonFile.write(doc.toJson());
    JsonFileModel jsonFileModel;
    jsonFileModel.addDetail(file, path, dateTime);
}

    void JsonCreator::loadJSONData(const QString path, const QString fileName, const QString currentTest){
        QString val;
        QFile file;
        file.setFileName(path + fileName);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        val = file.readAll();
        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
        convertJsonToQt(doc, currentTest);
    }
```

Qml list model code:

```
 ListModel{
        id: summaryModel1
        ListElement{key: "abc"; value:"v123"; unit: "u456"}
        ListElement{key: "abc"; value:"v123"; unit: "u456"}
        ListElement{key: "abc"; value:"v123"; unit: "u456"}
        ListElement{key: "abc"; value:"v123"; unit: "u456"}
}
ListModel{
        id: summaryModel2
        ListElement{key: "bac"; value:"v42"; unit: "u56"}
        ListElement{key: "bac"; value:"v42"; unit: "u56"}
        ListElement{key: "bac"; value:"v42"; unit: "u56"}
        ListElement{key: "bac"; value:"v42"; unit: "u56"}
}
ListModel{
        id: summaryModel3
        ListElement{key: "cab"; value:"v12"; unit: "u45"}
        ListElement{key: "cab"; value:"v12"; unit: "u45"}
        ListElement{key: "cab"; value:"v12"; unit: "u45"}
        ListElement{key: "cab"; value:"v12"; unit: "u45"}
}

Connections{
        target: jsonCreator
        onResultsDataChanged: {
            var summaries = [summaryModel1, summaryModel2, summaryModel3, summaryModel4, summaryModel5, summaryModel7, summaryModel8]
            var str = "";
            summaries.forEach(function(element){
                for(var i = 0; i < element.count; ++i){
                    var key = element.get(i).key
                    var name = element.get(i).name
                    var val = element.get(i).value
                    var unit = element.get(i).unit
                    var val1 = element.get(i).value1
                    var unit1 = element.get(i).unit1
                    str =  key+","+ val
                }
            });
           jsonCreator.testData(currentTestTitle, str);
        }
    }
```

needs result :

```
{
    "test": {
        "abc": "v123",
        "abc": "v123",
        "abc": "v123",
        "abc": "v123",
        "bac": "v42",
        "bac": "v42",
        "bac": "v42",
        "bac": "v42",
        "cab": "v12",
        "cab": "v12",
        "cab": "v12",
        "cab": "v12"
    }
}
```

Comment: From experience it is easier the other way around, having your data on the Qt side.

Comment: No C++ needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730166/how-to-save-and-restore-the-content-of-a-listmodel/48731400#48731400

Comment: Of course, you can iterate model item objects manually to serialize in a custom format, but it is pointless since JSON already does that for you, and also provides deserialization out of the box and works for arbitrary data structures.