# can I save and retrieve the delegate of a delegatemodel in qml

Tags: qml, kde-plasma

I have a `Gridview` of `PlasmaCore.IconItem {}` 's.The model of `GridView` is a `DelegateModel` with `model`  property, the `Kicker.RootModel`.The delegate is a `MouseArea` which includes the `PlasmaCore.IconItem {}` 's and I have defined a `DropArea`  and implemented Drag and Drop ability.Below is a snippet of the code:

```js
GridView {
    id: gridView   
    anchors.fill: parent   
    cellWidth:  cellSizeWidth
    cellHeight: cellSizeHeight   
    property int lastChangedIndex: -1
    property int xAxis: 0
    property int yAxis: 0
    
    model: DelegateModel {
        id: visualModel
        
        model: searching ?  runnerModel.modelForRow(0): rootModel.modelForRow(0).modelForRow(index)
        
        delegate: MouseArea {
            id: delegateRoot
            property alias actdotTimer: activedotTimer
            property string outputText:''
            property string activedotCmd: "wmctrl -l"
            
            Connections {
                target: executableAct
                onExited: {
                    var formattedText = stdoutAct
                    
                    outputText  = formattedText
                }
            }
            
            Component.onCompleted:{
                executableAct.execAct(activedotCmd)
                activedotTimer.start()
            }                                
            
            signal run
            
            Timer{
                id:activedotTimer
                triggeredOnStart : true
                interval:1000
                
                running:mainItemRoot.containsMouse
                
                onTriggered:{
                    delegateRoot.run()
                    
                }
            }
            onRun:{
                executableAct.execAct(activedotCmd)
                
            }
            
            property bool held: false
            property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex
            
            TextMetrics {
                id: textMetrics
                text:model.display
                elide: Text.ElideMiddle
                elideWidth: 120
            }
            
            width: cellSizeWidth
            height: cellSizeHeight
            
            drag.target: held ? icon : undefined
            
            onPressed: {
                held = true
                icon.opacity = 0.5
            }
            onReleased: {
                icon.inPersistedItems = true
                if (held === true) {
                    held = false
                    icon.opacity = 1
                    icon.Drag.drop()
                } else {
                    //action on release
                }
            }
            
            onClicked:{
                activedotTimer.start()
                //console.log(model.favoriteId.replace('applications:',''));
                executable.exec("$(gtk-launch " + model.favoriteId.replace('applications:','') + ")") ;
                root.toggle();
                // console.log(model.display)
            }
            
            PlasmaCore.IconItem {
                id: icon
                x: iconSize*0.5
                width: iconSize//units.iconSizes.enormous
                height: width
                visible: true
                animated: false
                usesPlasmaTheme: false
                source: model.decoration
                
                PlasmaComponents.Label  {
                    id: appsdocsLabel
                    anchors.topMargin:30
                    anchors.top: icon.verticalCenter//botto
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: icon.horizontalCenter
                    
                    text:textMetrics.elidedText
                    color:"white"
                    
                }                                   
                
                Drag.active: delegateRoot.drag.active
                Drag.source: delegateRoot
                //Drag.hotSpot.x: 36
                //Drag.hotSpot.y: 36
                Drag.hotSpot:Qt.point(icon.width / 2, icon.height / 2)
                
                states: [
                    State {
                        when: icon.Drag.active
                        
                        ParentChange {
                            target: icon
                            parent: gridView
                        }
                        
                        AnchorChanges {
                            target: icon
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                            anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                        }
                    }
                ]
                
            }
            
            DropArea {
                id: dropArea
                
                anchors {
                    fill: parent
                    //margins: 0
                }
                
                signal trigger
                
                Timer {
                    id: dropZoneTimer
                    interval: 1000
                    onTriggered: {
                        dropArea.trigger()
                    }
                }
                onTrigger: {
                    visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex,
                                           delegateRoot.visualIndex)
                    gridView.lastChangedIndex = delegateRoot.visualIndex
                }
                
                onEntered: {
                    if (drag.source.visualIndex !== delegateRoot.visualIndex) {
                        dropZoneTimer.start()
                    }
                }
                onExited: {
                    dropZoneTimer.stop()
                    gridView.lastChangedIndex = -1
                }
                onDropped: {
                    if (gridView.lastChangedIndex !== delegateRoot.visualIndex) {
                        visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex,
                                               delegateRoot.visualIndex)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now the code is working and I can drag and drop the icons .
The question is how can I save and retrieve the new position of the icons after drag and drop , between the restarts of the program or the PC.

Comment: the code is unreadable, please keep it to a minimum to focus only on the problem. Besides that, you can save the state using [Settings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) and restore that on startup

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience about the code.As far as ```Settings``` I've tryied  it but I can not get the model info (following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730166/how-to-save-and-restore-the-content-of-a-listmodel ) because it is a ```DelegateModel``` and not a ```ListModel```.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when working with `DelegateModel` I like to create multiple `DelegateModelGroup`s for maintaining multiple orders for things. It looks like you already use the default `items` group, but, that's the one you manipulate as well. Perhaps if you did something like this:

```
    DelegateModel {
        groups: [
            DelegateModelGroup {
                id: items
                name: "item"
                includeByDefault: true
            },
            DelegeteModelGroup {
                id: origItems
                name: "orig"
                includeByDefault: true
            }
         ]
     }
```

That way, every item in the DelegateModel will have both an `itemIndex` and `origIndex`. You can iterate through the `items` group and observe the `origIndex` of each item. Conversely, you can iterate through tie `origItems` group and observe the `itemIndex`, so you can lookup indexes in both forward and backward direction.